# Is it possible to get the cell reference instead of value obtained from : sample( matrix )?

Tags: r, random

I'm picking a random value from a matrix using the following code. probMatrix contains the probability weights for each cell. The `sample( )` returns a random cell value from the exampleMatrix.

```
probMatrix <- matrix(0.2,nrow=2,ncol=2)
exampleMatrix <- matrix(1:4,nrow=2,ncol=2)

sample(exampleMatrix, 1, prob=probMatrix)
```

I'd like to be able to get the reference/coordinates of the the matrix cell where random value has been pulled from. Is there a way to accomplish this?

I need the matrix cell co-ordinates to update the state of the system (probMatrix and exampleMatrix) I'm trying to simulate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the index, then sample form the possible indexes and extract the value with that index. You can get the row/col with `arrayInd`. For example

```
set.seed(22)
(si <- sample(1:length(exampleMatrix), 1, prob=probMatrix))
# [1] 3
(sv <- exampleMatrix[si])
# [1] 3
(scoor <- arrayInd(si, dim(exampleMatrix)))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    2
```